# Deploying Eclipse Java Dynamic web project on Apache Tomcat permanently

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a Java web project in Eclipse which I run through Eclipse on Apache Tomcat.

Is there a way for me to ***permanently*** deploy the project on Tomcat such that it runs ***without*** having to open Eclipse and rather just starting Tomcat?
If yes, then what steps do I need to follow?

****UPDATE****

If I take the .war file and deploy it on another system will it work? Note that I am using a MySql database in this project. So will transferring the .war file also transfer the database?

Comment: When people refer to the "Apache server" they typically mean the [Apache HTTP Server](https://projects.apache.org/projects/http_server.html), which is not a servlet container and cannot run Java web applications.  Are you referring to that, or to [Apache Tomcat](https://projects.apache.org/projects/tomcat.html)?

Comment: Oh sorry I should have mentioned that..I meant Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You package the project into a war file (since it is a web project) and put that one into the Tomcat's webapps folder. The deployment should then happen automatically, when Tomcat is started.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a WAR file within Eclipse. (Properties->Export->WAR File)
Place this file in the `{installation}/webapps` folder of Tomcat.
It should deploy now.